# Anyone can comment this ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I'm a total novice in ruby, i came across this code in an article about a bug in gmail:

```
(0..0xFFFFFFFFFF).each do |i|
  puts "#{"%010X" % i}"
end
```

it is supposed to generate an dictionary, but i can't figure out how it works

Thank You all!

Comment: http://www.orenh.com/2014/06/one-token-to-rule-them-all-tale-of.html


I can't figure out how it works

Comment: It just (in theory) generates all 10-digit hex codes, including leading zeroes, which is all valid token values for the vulnerable URL. The dictionary lookup is performed by another app calling the vulnerable URL, this code doesn't do anything else but count from 0 to a large number, in hex, one entry per line. The result is fed into a fast parallel web client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code iterates and prints all values from `0` to `0xFFFFFFFFFF` Similar to how

```
(1..10).each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

iterates and prints all values from 1 to 10.

For each value between `0` and `0xFFFFFFFFFF` it simply prints out its current hex value:

```
0000000000
       ...
0000005E6A
0000005E6B
0000005E6C
0000005E6D
0000005E6E
0000005E6F
       ...
FFFFFFFFFF
```